# Find the status change

Tags: sql, compare

I have a master table , say mast_tbl, where every change on this table goes as a different entry into hst_mast_tbl. There is col in both the tables which talks about status change. Now if I want to track the number of records for which only the status has changed in the past 10 days, how can I achieve it in a simplest way?

To use lag function, sometimes there might be more column getting updated in master table so more than 1 record in my history table. So how can I achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements, some sample data and the expected output. (_formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using triggers? If you are using SQL Server [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) might help you.
You can utilize the trigger by using FOR UPDATE when certain column is edited on your table you could say

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_update] ON [dbo].[tbl_trans]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @transaction VARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @action VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @ref_id INT
    DECLARE @trail_date DATETIME

    SELECT
        @transaction = '<your table here>',
        @action = 'Update',
        @ref_id = i.trans_id, 
        @trail_date = GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED i

    INSERT INTO tbl_auditTrail (audit_trans,action,ref_id,trail_date)
    VALUES (@transaction,@action,@ref_id,@trail_date)
END
GO
```

something like this.